# Why is pushing UINavigationController not allowed?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I'm well aware that `UINavigationController` shouldn't be pushed.  But I'm curious as to what it was designed for

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) for that class? There’s rather a lot of discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is pushing UINavigationController not allowed?

UINavigationController is a view controller that manages a stack of other view controllers. When you “push” a view controller,the stack you’re pushing it onto is managed by a navigation controller. Pushing a navigation controller onto its own stack or some other nav controller’s stack both seem problematic for lots of reasons. For example, from the user’s point of view, a nav controller pushed onto another nav controller’s stack could seem like adding a whole new stack of view controllers at once — it would make the UI jumpy and unpredictable.

What’s you’re reason for wanting to do this in the first place? If you can expand your question with a description of what you’re trying to accomplish, perhaps someone can help you find a better way.

Comment: This question was not asked in the face of an actual need, but rather a question of pure design intent. thank you ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: @O-O-wl Just think for a moment about what pushing a Mac controller would mean. How could that work for users?